# Bootstrap 3.0: clearing floats properly for nested divs

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float

I'm working with bootsrap 3.0 and getting confused with use of `clearfix class`. my question is if i've a structure like this

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12></div>
   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12></div>
   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12></div>

   <div class="clearfix></div> //is this proper place to clear floats for above divs ?  
  </div>
</div>
```

and along with other scenario  if i have to add nested divs e.g.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12>
      <div class="col-md-6"></div><!--inner div-->
      <div class="col-md-6"></div><!--inner div-->
     // how do i clear flaots for these ones 
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12></div>


   <div class="clearfix></div> //is this proper place to clear floats for above divs ?  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You might want to add the missing quotations in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the place is correct, but you might need to specify the view port that you want the `clearfix` to be applied to as explained in [bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets) so it would be:

```
<div class="clearfix visible-md-block visible-sm-block"></div>
```

For the other question. In bootstrap you cannot add nest columns without wrapping them in a div with a `row` class. So it should be like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6"></div><!--inner div-->
        <div class="col-md-6"></div><!--inner div-->
      </div>
    </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

for the previous example you don't need clearfix, because you have only two columns, however here's an example when you'll need clear fix:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6"></div>

        <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>

        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this example you have 4 columns in md break point, and 2 columns in sm, so if the sm break point is active, and the heights of the columns are different, you will need a clearfix div.  Notice, this is applied for the nested row.

You have to apply the same clearfix for every level of .col-**-** classes with variable heights.

Comment: And do i need to clear floats for inner blocks or its   fine if i cleared the outer ones ,

Comment: It depends on the scenario, for this example, there's no need.  It's preferred to put your columns in a row instead of clearfix.

Comment: I'll update the answer to show when you need to add clear fix